# Keycloak feasibility

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I was studying about Keycloak . Can anyone specify some solid thresholds where Keycloak is not feasible to be used?

Just need to know, where keycloak is identical to be used, looking at the answer one should be cleared that keycloak can't be used here or may be used. I searched on internet, they talk about latency, or number of concurrent users, if that's true than what Latency or what is a maximum number of concurrent server.